# How to know break point value in Padre?

Tags: perl, padre

I'm using padre for Perl debugging. Here I've set break point. After set break point, I try to move one by one. But I don't know how to know the variable value at the break point .

How to do that ?

and

What is the Best tool for Perl ?

Comment: Remove this question `What is the Best tool for Perl ?`, it is primarily opinion-based. ;)

Answer (score 2):

For debugging a Perl code, use `perl -d myscript.pl`

> b LINE_NUMBER for break-point.
>
> c to continue.
>
> n to skip internals of subroutine.
>
> s to enter into subroutine and debug each line of the subroutine.

For documentation, read [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html).

**OR**

Use `use re qw(debug);` package directly.

Check its documentation [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/re.html).